# How to change color in CANVAS with type="range"?

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

I want to change the blue color using a `type="range"` input, I have gotten this far [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Avve1000/v58meehk/3/). But need further assistance since I don´t have the knowledge to succeed with my task. Is it possiable/easier using jquery or javascript? I normally prefer jquery.

```
<svg id="ett">
<defs>
    <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="15" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect class="tva" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
<form>
<input type="range" id="testr">
</form>


#ett{border-style:solid;
height:250px;
width:250px;}
.tva{height:250px;
width:250px;
stroke:red;
stroke-width:50px;
fill:blue;}
```

Comment: Get the value of slider and assign color on greater than value

Answer (score 0):

Change in code below YOUR_CALCULATED_VALUE to calculated value. It should work.

```
$("input[type=range]").change(function(){
    console.log($(this).val()); // output in console current position
    $(".tva").css("fill", YOUR_CALCULATED_VALUE)
})
```